# passing generic type by Function(T) in flutter

Tags: generics, flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I'm trying to create a generic consumer widget that facilitates the ViewModel to its child. therefor I have two functions. one that has a function(T) after init of the ViewModel and the other for passing the model to its child Widget.

in the generic class  is a child of ChangeNotifier and that works fine until I want to send the T value in the two Functions.

then I get the following errors:

> type '(OnBoardingViewModel) => Null' is not a subtype of type
>   '(ChangeNotifier) => void'

and

> type '(BuildContext, OnBoardingViewModel, Widget) => Scaffold' is not
>   a subtype of type
>   '(BuildContext, ChangeNotifier, Widget) => Widget'

But when i change the extends type from ChangeNotifier to OnBoardingViewModel, everything works fine.

can someone help me and or explain why this ain't working??

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class StateFullConsumerWidget<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget{

  StateFullConsumerWidget({@required this.builder,Key key,this.onPostViewModelInit,this.child}) : super(key : key);

  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, ChangeNotifier value, Widget child) builder;
  final Widget child;

  final void Function(T) onPostViewModelInit;

  @override
  _StateFullConsumerWidgetState<T> createState() => _StateFullConsumerWidgetState<T>();
}

class _StateFullConsumerWidgetState<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends State<StateFullConsumerWidget>{
  T _viewModel;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // assign the model once when state is initialised
    _viewModel = GetIt.instance.get<T>();
    widget.onPostViewModelInit(_viewModel);


    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
      builder: (context) => _viewModel,
      child: Consumer<T>(
        builder: widget.builder,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

my widget

```
StateFullConsumerWidget<OnBoardingViewModel>(
      onPostViewModelInit: (viewModel){
        buildIntroList(viewModel);
        viewModel.maxPages = _introWidgetsList.length;
      },
      builder: (context,viewModel,child) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: widget.scaffoldKey,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

my ViewModel

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OnBoardingViewModel extends ChangeNotifier{

  OnBoardingViewModel(){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The way you are using the generic type `T` is incomplete. The relationship between the `StateFullConsumerWidget` and the `_StateFullConsumerWidgetState` classes as written in your code are such that `StateFullConsumerWidget` creates its state using the same `T` type parameter as itself, so the widget knows the state uses the same generic type that it does. From the perspective of `_StateFullConsumerWidgetState`, though, the class is declared as such:

```
class _StateFullConsumerWidgetState<T extends ChangeNotifier> 
    extends State<StateFullConsumerWidget>
```

The problem is the state class is using the general form of `StateFullConsumerWidget`, so there is no explicit relationship between the `T` that `_StateFullConsumerWidgetState` is receiving as the type parameter and the `T` that `StateFullConsumerWidget` is using. Dart doesn't know how to reconcile this ambiguous relationship, so it defaults to the lowest common denominator the type constraints allow, which is `ChangeNotifier`.

Because of this, when you try to treat `T` as `OnBoardingViewModel`, Dart throws an error because, as far as the state class knows, the `T` of the parent widget is `ChangeNotifier`, not `OnBoardingViewModel`.

You can fix this by passing the type parameter along when you declare your state class:

```
class _StateFullConsumerWidgetState<T extends ChangeNotifier> 
    extends State<StateFullConsumerWidget<T>>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not exactly sure why this is the case, but the dart compiler doesn't recognize the type T from the StateFullConsumerWidget as the same type T of the _StateFullConsumerWidgetState. If you pass the functions to the State everything works as expected.

Resulting code:

```
class StateFullConsumerWidget<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget{

  StateFullConsumerWidget({@required this.builder,Key key,this.onPostViewModelInit,this.child}) : super(key : key);

  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T value, Widget child) builder;
  final Widget child;

  final Function(T viewModel) onPostViewModelInit;

  @override
  _StateFullConsumerWidgetState<T> createState() => _StateFullConsumerWidgetState<T>(onPostViewModelInit, builder);
}

class _StateFullConsumerWidgetState<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends State<StateFullConsumerWidget>{
  final Function(T viewModel) _onPostViewModelInit;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T value, Widget child) _builder;
  T _viewModel;

  _StateFullConsumerWidgetState(this._onPostViewModelInit, this._builder);

  @override
  void initState() {
    // assign the model once when state is initialised
    _viewModel = GetIt.instance.get<T>();
    _onPostViewModelInit(_viewModel);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
      builder: (context) => _viewModel,
      child: Consumer<T>(
        builder: _builder,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```