# What type to be declared

Tags: flutter, dart, types

So there is a class like this

```
class Base<T extends BaseClass> extends StatefulWidget
```

and I want to use that class without directly give an Object that extends BaseClass but instead something pass through the constructor.

```
class Something extends StatelessWidget {
  final /*what type I am supposed to give here*/ test;

  const Something({Key key, this.test}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Base<test>();
  }
}
```

The error warning I get is

```
'dynamic' doesn't extend 'BaseClass'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'BaseClass'.dart(type_argument_not_matching_bounds)

The name 'test' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'test'.dart(non_type_as_type_argument)
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886661/passing-generic-type-by-functiont-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can declared by "Type", but cannot create an instance of a class from a Type object representing the class.

```
class Something<T extends BaseClass> extends StatelessWidget {
  // final Type test;

  // const Something({Key key, this.test}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Base<T>();
  }
}
```

Create Something widget:

```
class NewClass extends BaseClass {}

Widget x = Something<NewClass>();
```

Comment: So how am I supposed to give value for T in Base<T> if I can't pass the instance from constructor?

Comment: I add a create Something widget sample.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't fully work because all the fields that's supposed to be in T class can't be accessed, only be able to access the BaseClass

Comment: Of course, that's it only access known interface. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics